# How much track width should I leave while soldering metallised polypropylene capacitors carrying around 6.25 Amps?

Tags: soldering

I am not using a PCB for this and I would be soldering on a dot board and making the PCB tracks myself. I was advised that I make the solder tracks as wide as possible for allowing high current to flow. But how much exactly should I make the track width? Right now the solder track is around 16 mm wide and around 2 mm thick. Would this be sufficient? Also, the current will be passed relatively continuously.

Comment: If you do this on a veroboard, you  probably want to just solder some copper wire on and fill everything around it nicely with solder; much easier.

Comment: I have done exactly that. But I was told that it might not be able to carry that much current.

Comment: It always depends on how thick of wires and how much solder you add. Simply do it, measure voltage drop and heating, if it is not within specs, add more. Its a prototype after all, it is ok to look a bit messy ;)

Answer (score 1):

To carry 6.25A rms, 1mm2 of copper would be plenty, and you will get away with half that, at least as far as wire heating is concerned.

If you have 2mm  thick and 16mm wide, that's 32mm2, total overkill if it's copper. I hope you haven't layered on solder to make up the thickness. It's much higher resistivity and much more expensive than copper.

Comment: If solder was more expensive than copper, cheap chinese fabs would not use it to increase ampacity of traces.

Comment: It isn't layered up tbh, but probably just thicker solder. How much of a cross section would this need to be?